# AccessDenied Error while using Psutil library in MacOs via Jython

Tags: java, macos, jython, psutil

I am trying to use psutil library in MacOS via Jython but when I make a call to psutil.cpu_times function, I get the following error.

```
        except AccessDenied as err:
```

In psutil documentation the reason is explained as following.

> Note (OSX) psutil.AccessDenied is always raised unless running as root
>   (lsof does the same).

Is there a way to overcome this problem? I will run the program in Linux enviroment after development so a temporary solution will be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who land on this page looking for an answer to the same question. I couldn't find a solution to this problem and returned back to extracting system status from /sys.